How do i find an app service which is consuming high CPU% in an app service plan?
Looks like recently there was a change from microsoft side. I have an app service plan which has 5 apps in it.
The plan has hit 98% CPU. i want to know which app is consuming high CPU. I am unable to find that information.
Earlier i used to go to Diagnose and Solve problems --> High CPU Usage -- which was listing all the apps with CPU%
Now i dont see that option anymore.

The option to list High CPU Analysis is now available only for each individual App Service.


To know the CPU time for Each App Service in Azure App Service plan,you can check Diagnose and solve problems => CPU/Memory


OR
Under Monitoring => Metrics


Add metrics,with each App Service Name.


